# How can I figure out the distance to Juno at any point in time?

Tags: orbital-mechanics, trajectory, amateur-radio, flyby, juno

Juno will fly by Earth on October 9, 2013. There is [an event](http://www.jpl.nasa.gov/hijuno/) to encourage Amateur Radio Operators to say high to the satellite. What I'm trying to do is figure out if I have any chance of pulling it off. In order to do that, I need to know the distance to Juno at a particular moment in time. How might I best be able to figure this out?

Comment: Did you try? If so, any luck? I thought the idea was if enough hams just point and shoot (transmit), the aggregate signal would only show as an elevated noise measurement at a certain moment. It wasn't like it would personally reply to people, was it?

Comment: I did participate, and even got a nice card. They did detect some kind of a signal.

Comment: I didn't know that Juno had time to stop by a post office, wow you're luck! ;)

Comment: LOL. Basically anyone who made the attempt sent a notice to NASA, who sent out cards to everyone who attempted.

Answer (score 5):

The [JPL HORIZONS](http://ssd.jpl.nasa.gov/horizons.cgi) website is what you want for precise, tabulated values. Using the web interface, you can specify your position, and get all the info you could need for a given body (in your case, observer-centric (?) range to JUNO). It will also give you relevant parameters if you wanted to try and (visually) observe it, such as pointing angles, and the Sun-Spacecraft-Observer angle.

Answer (score 3):

The event web-site you posted shows the[ground-track](http://www.jpl.nasa.gov/hijuno/images/EFB_publicmap1.png), and a [list of cities](http://missionjuno.swri.edu/hijuno/static/pdf/Juno_EFB_Waves_Ham_Radio_Headings_00.pdf) to orient a directional antenna .

[This site](http://missionjuno.swri.edu/news/status-20130916) also writes to say

> See Juno’s current position, speed and more via NASA’s Eyes on the Solar System 3D interactive. [Launch the Juno module](http://bit.ly/junoeotss) or view Juno in the standard [Eyes on the Solar System](http://eyes.nasa.gov/) interface.

Hope this helps! I'm QRU unfortunately )+: